# Is it possible to view a notebook note in mind-map form?

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, output-formatting, visualization, slideshows

There are many people who are more comfortable with the display style of mind-maps; I wonder if it is possible to display a notebook (whose contents have been properly formatted as Chapters Sections, etc.) in the form of mind-maps? If there are no built-in approaches, is it possible to realize this functionality with the aid of some code?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a start. Because in Wolfram Language ["Everything Is an Expression"](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Expressions.html) you can use built-in structures and parsers to view it as a tree. For example, this creates a notebook with some content:

```
nb = CreateNotebook["ComputationalEssay"]
```

And this transforms it into a tree

```
ExpressionTree[NotebookImport[nb, _, "FlattenCellGroups" -> False]]
```

[image]

You will have to make it more tailored to what you want but I think most of what you would need is well described in documentation.

Comment: That's very nice